# Сортировка кортежа данных

Tags: python, tuple

Есть два кортежа

```
tuple1 = ('number', 'name', 'type', 'salary')
```

и

```
tuple2 = ('number', 'salary', 'name' 'type')
         (1, 13000, 'Danya', 'designer')
         (2, 15000, 'Lubov', 'programmer')
         (3, 20000, 'Nastya', 'seo')
```

Мне нужно:

1. Изменить порядок tuple2, сделать его таким как tuple1.
   Если есть примеры, скиньте пожалуйста как это сделать?
   tuple2 нужно сделать его таким:

   ```
   tuple2 = ('number', 'name', 'type' 'salary')
         (1, Danya, 'designer', 13000)
         (2, Lubov, 'programmer', 15000)
         (3, Nastya, 'seo', 20000)
   ```

Comment: Можно поподробнее, что надо?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, тупль неизменяем. Но задача, похоже, совсем в другом - вот и расскажите о задаче.

Comment: больше похоже на задачу перемещения столбцов

Comment: @MBo это парсинг excel, в файле 2 страницы sheet1 и sheet2. У них одинковые  столбцы но лежат в разброс

Comment: @Zhihar да нужно переместить стобцы

Comment: Списки вместо кортежей используйте

Comment: @MBo спасибо за совет.